# How does the Truevault API exactly work? [request clarification]

Tags: truevault

I'm currently working with a health company that requests their patient data to be HIPAA compliant.

Being unfamiliar with HIPAA Compliance, after research, I found sites like Truevault that offer HIPAA compliance databases so patient data is securely stored and cannot be stolen.

However, when reading the documentation of their REST Api, I was confused exactly what is the "database" part of Truevault. Their documentation supports APIs for vaults and documents. Vaults store the douments.

Here is my specific question: In the Truevualt Api, would I securely send data to Truevault through a document? If not, then do I need to use another third party service (such as Parse) to first gather the patient data and THEN send it to Truevault?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

TrueVault accepts JSON documents, which we receive via our RESTful API. Furthermore, this data is typically sent from client-side applications directly to TrueVault.

If you have any other questions or need clarification, you can reach us via our [Community Forums](https://discuss.truevault.com/).

Cheers,

Dan Cleary

Customer Success Engineer at TrueVault